# Broken keyboard shortcuts

Tags: 10.10, gnome, keyboard, shortcuts

When I freshly installed maverick on my new notebook, I set up my keyboard shortcuts like this: Switch to WS 1 = `Mod4+1`, Move Window to WS 1 = `Mod4+Shift+1`, Switch to WS 2 = `Mod4+2` and so on (Mod4 being the "Windows" key). But now the three-key combinations (i.e. the ones I use for "move to...") stopped working. When I go to keyboard preferences, I still see them and I can even change them to a different combination and then again to the desired one - but they won't execute the window movement afterwards :/ Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Compiz is preventing these shortcuts to work. Can you try this:

```
metacity --replace
```

Then try your shortcuts.

**Else, if you want your visual effects by Compiz, you can do a trick:**

If you are using Compiz, you will have to do a trick because Compiz "workspaces" are actually Viewports of a single Workspace.

We will need [wmctrl](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/wmctrl) and [Compiz](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager).

You can install these from the *Ubuntu Software Center* or by clicking [here (wmctrl)](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/wmctrl) and [here (Compiz)](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager)

**The Shortcuts**

**#** Open Compiz (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `ccsm` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

**#** Go to Keybindings and make the shortcuts you want.

**#** Then go to Commands and add the commands for yours shortcuts (see below).

**The Commands (Trick Instructions)**

Go to a terminal and check the output of `wmctrl -d`. For example, mine is:

> 0  * DG: 4098x2304  VP: 1366,0  WA: 0,23 1366x745  N/A

This means that actually I have one Workspace of 4098 x 2304 instead of what I "think" I have (nine "workspaces", 3 x 3).
I was at what was supposed to be "workspace" 2, but actually I was at viewport (VP) 1366,0 (4098 / 3 = 1366) as showed by the output above.

So this is how it works: we take the whole Workspace and divide for the numbers of "workspaces" we "think" we have. In my case: 4098 / 3 = 1366 and 2304 / 3 = 768.

if I want to go to my "workspace" 1, the command is:
`wmctrl -o 0,0`

Then, if I want to go to my "workspace" 4, the command is:
`wmctrl -o 0,768`

if I want to go to my "workspace" 8, the command is:
`wmctrl -o 1366,1536`

if I want to go to my "workspace" 9, the command is:
`wmctrl -o 2732,1536`

Got it?  ;-)

Comment: I'm on Maverick and don't want to change the Window Manager, just the old behavior back :)

Comment: metacity --replace,  /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/compiz-decorator. This is a plain maverick installation, really. I did not customize the window manager etc., just added my keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks, that works fine. It obviously deactivates desktop effects, but keyboard shortcuts are more important until I have the time to investigate how I can fix compiz.

Comment: I've made a trick for you, so you don't need to disable Compiz. Hope you like ;-)